# java.lang.NullPointerException session.getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I am trying to import a successful project maven into eclipse but it doesn't work. So I decided to cut most of it and leave only the essential part to find out what's wrong with it. So I've got:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project")
public class DBConfiguration
{

  @Resource
  Environment mEnvironment;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() 
  {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=Project_DB");
    dataSource.setUsername("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("pass");
    return dataSource;
  }

  public Properties hibernateProperties()
  {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    return properties;
  }

  @Bean
  public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException
  {    
    try
    {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
      sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.project");
      sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
      sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
      return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed.");
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager()  throws IOException
  {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

Then another class just to test whether it works:

```
@Repository
public class Dao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void getCurrentSession() 
    {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

And the another test class:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dao dao = new Dao();
        dao.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

After calling this class I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException session.getCurrentSession()
```

My `pom.xml` is:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <sql.server.conector.version>4.0</sql.server.conector.version>
    <freemarker.version>2.3.21</freemarker.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DBConnectionPool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DBCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--SQL Server Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>${sql.server.conector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- FreeMarker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet Api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Aspect J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Update: when I allow spring to initialize the beans I get the following error:

```
Mar 22, 2015 2:20:31 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@421faab1: startup date [Sun Mar 22 14:20:31 GMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Mar 22, 2015 2:20:33 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Mar 22, 2015 2:20:33 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
Mar 22, 2015 2:20:33 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 22, 2015 2:20:33 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.
Mar 22, 2015 2:21:04 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.Dao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.Dao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration.sessionFactory(DBConfiguration.java:63)
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e957439.CGLIB$sessionFactory$3(<generated>)
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e957439$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c805d05f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e957439.sessionFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:500)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:172)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:49)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration.sessionFactory(DBConfiguration.java:58)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: connect timed out. Please verify the connection properties and check that a SQL Server instance is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:130)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1195)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.loginWithoutFailover(SQLServerConnection.java:1054)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:758)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:57)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:63)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:396)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:498)
    ... 53 more

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.Dao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.Dao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration.sessionFactory(DBConfiguration.java:63)
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e957439.CGLIB$sessionFactory$3(<generated>)
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e957439$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c805d05f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e957439.sessionFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:500)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:172)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:49)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at com.utilisoft.urlshortener.config.DBConfiguration.sessionFactory(DBConfiguration.java:58)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: connect timed out. Please verify the connection properties and check that a SQL Server instance is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:130)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1195)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.loginWithoutFailover(SQLServerConnection.java:1054)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:758)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:57)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:63)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:396)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:498)
    ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're instantiating `dao` directly instead of allowing Spring to create the bean. You could do

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

ctx.register(DBConfiguration.class);
ctx.refresh();

Dao dao = ctx.getBean(Dao.class);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, please see my updated answer. It still fails to initialize the sessionFactory..

Comment: If OP cared to post the correct part of the stacktrace (the root cause), it may have been resolvable.

Comment: Hi Marko, I've pasted the whole stacktrace

Comment: Well, don't you find it self-explanatory? `The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: connect timed out. Please verify the connection properties and check that a SQL Server instance is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.`

Comment: I reinstalled ms management studio and the TCP/IP is disabled by default. I enabled it and it runs ok. 10x for your help